# Tracking user's activity

Tags: android, android-activity

HI
I am intereseted in developing an application, which will track user's activities on phone
like
1.calls
2.messages
3.Packet data
4.GPS Usages
5.Media Usage
6.Apps usage
Please let me know if there is a way to achieve these.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty certain that there is no way to achieve this without using a customized ROM for very good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Calls, messages and packet data are already tracked by the system, there are many applications on the market that display or analyze these statistics. Don't know about GPS, media and apps usage.